# In an Android application, how do I maximize Form 1 when returning to it from a secondary form?

Tags: android, forms, delphi

I am coding a multi-form Android application in Delphi. When the Main Menu form launches, it is fullscreen as desired. When I go from there to a second form using *NameOfForm2.Form.Show* that, too, is fullscreen, as desired. But when I attempt to return to the Main Menu form by using *NameOfForm2.Form.Close*, the phone's status bar showing the clock and battery level is now visible as is the bottom three-icon panel. How do I prevent this?

**What I have tried:**
I have tried setting the Main Menu Form's FullScreen property to True and its BorderStyle to None and its WindowState property to wsMaximized in the Object Inspector but this makes no difference. I have tried making the same changes programmatically in the FormActivate event, but this, too, makes no difference.

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Form1.FullScreen := TRUE;
 Form1.WindowState := TWindowState(2);
 Form1.BorderStyle := TFmxFormBorderStyle(0);
 LoadMainMenu();
end;
```

Comment: You may need to provide a more complete example, or more complete steps of how to reproduce this

Answer (score 0):

try this code on Event onCreate

```
uses
..., Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNI.App, Androidapi.Helpers;

...
...

begin
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.getWindow.setFlags(TJWindowManager_LayoutParams.JavaClass.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, TJWindowManager_LayoutParams.JavaClass.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
end;
```

it's make your apps fullscreen.